# How to manually update apps

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, applications, updates

I have Android 4.0 and I'm trying to figure out how to manually update all of my apps when the update notification usually at the top of the screen is NOT there. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform updates on installed APP's accessing the Play Store:

1. Find the Play Store icon on your home screen or in your app drawer and tap it to open it up.
2. Once the Play Store loads, tap the menu button on your device and choose the "My Apps" option.
3. Wait until the list gets filled. If there are available updates you'll see::

   - A text that says "Update" to the right of the app's name, you can long press it to update that APP;
   - Additionally, you can press "update" on the top of the list to update all APP's.

     Usually a number is present to the right, that refers to the total number of updates available.